# Sorting by attr value with tinysort won't work in desc

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I am trying to make use of [tyniSort](http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/) to sort a list witht the following markup

```
<ul>
   <li><a c="50">uno</a></li>
   <li><a c="22">dos</a></li>
  <li><a c="2000">tres</a></li>
</ul>
```

i have onclick this

```
orden = 'asc';
if($(this).hasClass('desc')){
           orden = 'desc';
}
$(this).parent().prev('ul').find('li').tsort('a',{attr:'c'},{order:orden});
$(this).toggleClass('desc');
```

As you can see, thanks of the toggleClass it should toggle asc/desc order for every click,

the thing is that in asc works but in desc doesnt; no errors at firebug or warnings and the list stays the same...

any idea why?

Comment: `$(this).parent().prev('ul').find('li').tsort('a',{attr:'c'},{order:orden});` shouldn't read `$(this).parent().prev('ul').find('li').tsort('a',{attr:'c', order:orden});`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('ul').click(function() { 
    orden = 'asc'; 

    if ($(this).hasClass('desc')) { 
        orden = 'desc'; 
    }

    $(this).find('li').tsort('a', { attr: 'c', order: orden }); 
    $(this).toggleClass('desc'); 
});
```